# Extract amplitude values from a wav file

Tags: audio, amplitude

I would like to extract the amplitude value from a wav file. Using Python I can extract the raw data into an array. How do I go about extracting the amplitude value of each sample?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question. The raw data IS proportional of the amplitude of the sound pressure.

Comment: Do you mean the *amplitude* ***envelope***?

Comment: Hi Hitesh! Welcome to DSP.SE. I assume there may be a confusion on what you are referring to as amplitude. It would help if you could please provide an example of the first few samples and describe where you are confused in what the amplitude of each of those samples are.

Comment: Apologies I should have been more specific. I am trying to extract the amplitudes associated with a wav file and am able to do that successfully. I then pitch shift the wav file by lets say 15% and then extract the amplitudes again. I assumed that pitch shifting would have no effect on the amplitudes and that I would be able to match the outputs from the original and pitch shifted files. However I am not able to do that even though a plot of the two files seems to out the same amplitude signature.  Any help on this would be most appreciated.

Comment: I am not sure that this could help, but have you considered using some kind of Dynamic-Time-Warping algorithm to try and match various parts of the two files? Additionally, I believe that the algorithm/method you used to shift the pitch of your file could possibly affect the final result (sample-wise).